# Can I set other coordinates in method "findCurrentPlace()"?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

I know this method takes device's currently location and find places where the device is likely to be located, but i don`t  khow to get places from another coordinats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you give a bit more context in your question, e.g. where does the method come from? I will try to answer it nevertheless :-)

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place#get-current) states that you need to

> Create a FindCurrentPlaceRequest, passing a List of Place.Fields, specifying the place data types your app should request.

and pass this request to the `PlacesClient.findCurrentPlaces`. If you are talking about a different method, then please update your question.

EDIT: If you are looking for places at a different location, then you can use `fetchPlace` to [fetch a place](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/net/PlacesClient#public-abstract-taskfetchplaceresponse-fetchplace-fetchplacerequest-request) by place id. You can fetch a place id by coordinates following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically).

Comment: Yes I use method from PlacesClient class, and i get current places. But I need to get places by another coordinats

Comment: I do not fully understand you. You need to provide place data **types**, e.g. `Place.Field.NAME` and no coordinates...

Comment: ahh.. I think now I understand what you are looking for. You want to fetch the places at a different location, correct?

Comment: I have thought about it, but I don't know how to get place id

Comment: I updated my answer again on how to get a place id. hope that it helps you!

Comment: Place.builder().setLatLng(latLng).build();
Place.builder().build().getId();                                                                                            I try use this code, but i get null

Comment: No, I was wrong, it is not working like that. It seems that you could get a place id by following https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically

Comment: "Required: A query string containing the text typed by the user.", But i have only coordinates

Comment: Can you try an empty string and a very small radius around the coordinates?

Comment: I tried with empty string and it doesn`t work, but this works when I passing name of place

Comment: Can you try to pass the coordinates as string as the query string, e.g. like (lat, lng)?

Comment: I found the right way to do this, need implement GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener and there you can get "placeId", thank you for your time